# linux mint 20.1 - suddenly getting an unexplained icon overlayed on screen

Tags: linux, linux-mint

This seems like a basic problem but I haven't been able to find anyone discussing it.

Brand new laptop running latest Linux Mint.  Suddenly today an icon appears in center of screen, near the bottom.   It overlays and obstructs everything, but it's unclear why it's appeared or what it's indicating.  I haven't changed any settings or even rebooted, it just appeared and I can't figure out how to reset it.

I'm including a screenshot.  It looks like a trackpad or touchpad icon.  I thought perhaps accessibility accidentally was switched on, but 1) it's still off and 2) the icon doesn't respond to when you click it, it doesn't change w/respect to using touchpad, etc.  3) even if trackpad is disabled, it remains there.

[image]

Really confusing as I've used mint for years and never had an issue like this.   I have no custom applets or panels and the icon is displayed in same space regardless of what monitor (or just built-in laptop monitor) is used.   dmesg shows nothing of significance.

Clearly this icon is trying to tell me something because it's so intrusive.  However I have no idea what it is.  I can't find something similiar in google images.

Anybody know what causes this to show up and how I can remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was painful enough I did more research...

The closest thing I can find is the '[ubuntu touchpad-indicator](https://github.com/atareao/Touchpad-Indicator)' PPA.
The icon for this looks almost identical, but I do not use the PPA nor have this binary installed.

I did check xprops for which process id I could get from this area of the screen.  It came back with nemo's pid (same as non-trackpad background of screen).  Though I'm not sure how meaningful this is.

I scoured the desktop extensions to see if something had somehow gotten turned on, but everything seemed to be defaults from new install.

Still no idea what this is or how it got enabled, but restarting WM with ctrl+alt+esc caused the icon to go away.

If anybody knows what this icon was/is indicating, would love to know.

Comment: so,  are you saying that you did not do any research before you posted your question?   ... also, how does this answer your question?